# import package that using module federation

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I have a package that is being used as remote package of moudule federation machanism.
so when I build the package using webpack I get a build folder with remote-entry.js file in it. I also want that other package will be able to consume this package using npm.
but I don't have index.js file in my build folder , only remote-entry file.

how to I build my package that it will be consumed both by module federation and as npm package. ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set entry point to any file with [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#main)